# How do I create a test bulb?

Tags: philips-hue

I am trying to test an app I am working on and I want to see how it works with multiple and different bulbs, but I don't have as many lights as I would like.

Is there any way to create a "fake" bulb that acts like a normal hue bulb and works with the hue app? Basically, I want to trick Hue into believing that there are a few more lights connected to the bridge.

Comment: While I understand what you are trying to do, I don't think that is possible

Comment: I don't think you can create fake bulbs in the bridge. If you are stuck and you want a beta tester I'll help you out. I've got 24 bulbs in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test the UI with more lights than you have, why not just create your own PHLight objects? This will not let you interact with them ofcourse, but you can test certain UI elements (test a listview with more lights for example)